# php оставить 2 первых и 2 последних символа в строке, остальное заменить

Tags: php

Помогите с substr_replace

Нужно оставить 2 первых и 2 последних символа в строке, остальное заменить на звезды (т.е чтобы кол-во звезд было равно количеству символов которые были заменены)

```
$myname = substr_replace($myname, '***', 2, -2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myname = substr_replace($myname, str_pad("", strlen($myname)-4, "*"), 2, -2);
```